# Set the position of a widget programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to set the position of a widget. I tried like this:

```
Button Button10;
Button10 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.butonul10);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2; 
params2.AddRule (LayoutRules.Below, Button10);
```

And it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. I have replaced Button10 with Resource.Id.butonul10.

```
params2.AddRule (LayoutRules.Below, Resource.Id.butonul10);
```